# How do I scrape different data-stats that live under the same div using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

first = ()
first_slice = ()
last = ()


def askname():
    global first
    first = input(str("First Name of Player?"))
    global last
    last = input(str("Last Name of Player?"))
    print("Confirmed, loading up " + first + " " + last)
# asks user for player name

askname()

first_slice_result = (first[:2])
last_slice_result = (last[:5])
print(first_slice_result)
print(last_slice_result)
# slices player's name so it can match the format bref uses
first_slice_resultA = str(first_slice_result)
last_slice_resultA = str(last_slice_result)

first_last_slice = last_slice_resultA + first_slice_resultA

lower = first_last_slice.lower() + "01"

start_letter = (last[:1])
lower_letter = (start_letter.lower())
# grabs the letter bref uses for organization

print(lower)
source = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/' + lower_letter + '/' + lower + '.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tbody = soup.find('tbody')
pergame = tbody.find(class_="full_table")
classrite = tbody.find(class_="right")
tr_body = tbody.find_all('tr')
# lprint(pergame)

for td in tbody:
    print(td.get_text)

print("done")

get = str(input("What stat? \nCheck commands.txt for statistic names. \n"))

for trb in tr_body:
    print(trb.get('id'))
    print("\n")

    th = trb.find('th')
    print(th.get_text())
    print(th.get('data-stat'))

    row = {}
    for td in trb.find_all('td'):
        row[td.get('data-stat')] = td.get_text()

    print(row[get])
```

So I have this program that scrapes divs based on their given a "data-stat" value.  (pg_per_mp etc)
However right now I can only get that data-stat value from either assigning it a variable or getting it from an input. I would like to make a list of data-stats and grab all the values from each data-stat in the list.

for example

```
list = [fga_per_mp, fg3_per_mp, ft_per_mp]

for x in list:
   print(x)
```

In a perfect world, the script would take each value of the list and scrape the website for the assigned stat.

I tried editing line 66 - 79 to:

```
get = [fga_per_mp, fg3_per_mp]

for trb in tr_body:
    print(trb.get('id'))
    print("\n")

    th = trb.find('th')
    print(th.get_text())
    print(th.get('data-stat'))

    row = {}
    for td in trb.find_all('td'):
        for x in get():
          row[td.get('data-stat')] = td.get_text()
```

.. but of course that wouldn't work. Any help?

Comment: what is an example of the url that you are passing into the program?

Comment: an example would be "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/l/lowryky01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid hard coding the player id as it may not always follow that same pattern. What I would do is pull in the player names ad Ids (since the site provides it), then using something like fuzzywuzzy to match player name input (in case for typos and what not.

Once you get that, it's just a matter of pulling out the specific `<td>` tage with the chosen `data-stat`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

#pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import process

#pip install choice
import choice



def askname():
    playerNameInput = input(str("Enter the player's name -> "))
    return playerNameInput


# Get all player IDs
player_df = pd.read_csv('https://www.basketball-reference.com/short/inc/sup_players_search_list.csv', header=None)
player_df = player_df.rename(columns={0:'id',
                                      1:'playerName',
                                      2:'years'})
playersList = list(player_df['playerName'])

# asks user for player name
playerNameInput = askname()


# Find closest matches
search_match = pd.DataFrame(process.extract(f'{playerNameInput}', playersList))
search_match = search_match.rename(columns={0:'playerName',1:'matchScore'})

matches = pd.merge(search_match, player_df, how='inner', on='playerName').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
choices = [': '.join(x) for x in list(zip(matches['playerName'], matches['years']))]

# Choice the match
playerChoice = choice.Menu(choices).ask()
playerName, years = playerChoice.split(': ')

# Get that match players id
match = player_df[(player_df['playerName'] == playerName) & (player_df['years'] == years)]

baseUrl = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players'
playerId = match.iloc[0]['id']

url = f'{baseUrl}/{playerId[0]}/{playerId}.html'


html = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
statList = ['fga_per_mp', 'fg3_per_mp', 'ft_per_mp', 'random']
for stat in statList:
    try:
        statTd = soup.find('td', {'data-stat':stat})
        print(statTd['data-stat'], statTd.text)
    except:
        print(f'{stat} stat not found')
```

Comment: looks like that works perfectly! thank you so much! I just had a couple questions if you have some spare time 1. What's up with "html = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')"? What do the "replace" segments do?   2. Can you point out which lines utilize pandas?

Comment: ah ya. so some of the tables in the sports reference.com site come in within the comments in the html. That removes the comments tags so beautifulsoup won't skip it when it "finds" the tags.

Comment: pandas is used anytime you se `pd.`